# ZF view navigation helper: How to set several menu for one view?

Tags: zend-framework, menu, zend-view, zend-navigation

I have two xml menu. I set it up this way:

```
<?php echo $this->Navigation($this->menuPrivate)->menu(); ?>
<hr />
<?php echo $this->Navigation($this->interfaceMenu)->menu(); ?>
<?php
echo '<pre><br/>';
var_dump($this->Navigation($this->interfaceMenu));
die();
?>
```

Within var_dump is correct data. But the menu rendering shows me the same result - `$this->interfaceMenu` the same as `$this->menuPrivate`.

So is it possible to setup different menu for one view?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my fault. It should be look like:

```
<?php echo $this->Navigation()->menu($this->menuPrivate); ?>
<hr />
<?php echo $this->Navigation()->menu($this->interfaceMenu); ?>
```